# Can you explain where is my error?

Tags: integral-equations, initial-value-problems

Convert  given IVP
$$y''-\sin x\ y'+e^xy=x \tag{1}$$ $y(0)=0;y'(0)=1 $ to the integral form.

My attempt:-
I substitute $u(x)=y''(x)$. The we get on integration.

$$y'(x)=y'(0)+\int_{0}^x u(t)dt$$
 $$y(x)=y(0)+x+\int_0^x \int_{0}^u u(t)dt du$$

We know that $\int_0^x \int_{0}^u u(t)dt du=\int_0^x (x-t)u(t)dt$.

So, our (1) becomes $$u(x)-\sin(x)( 1+\int_{0}^x u(t)dt)+e^x(x+\int_0^x (x-t)u(t)dt)=x $$

But Answer given in the text is by the substitution $y''=x+\sin x y'+e^x y$.
Final answer was $y(x)=1-x+x^3/6+\int_0^x[\sin t-\cos t(x-t)-e^t(x-t)]y(t)dt$ which entirely different from my answer. Can you explain where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

You have
$y(x)=y(0)+x+\int_0^x \int_{0}^x u(t)dt dt
.$

For one thing,
the variables of integration must
have to be distinct,
so this should be
$y(x)
=y(0)+x+\int_0^x \int_{0}^s u(t)dt ds
$.

Second,
the double integral should be
(I think)
$y(x)
=y(0)+x+\int_0^x \int_{0}^s u(t)dt ds
$.

With this,
you can reverse the
order of integration.

Comment: Actually I just followed the notation that is in "https://www.amazon.com/First-Course-Integral-Equations-Second/dp/9814675121". Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Is my answer correct?